# Truncate NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I tried using defaultParagraphStyle, but I can't seem to get a NSTextView (programmatically added) to truncate text with an ellipsis (...).

I am setting the frame during the initWithFrame (150, 20) and I also set the maxSize (150,20). However, text simply overflows. If I set the height where half a line is visible, I can see the top half of the text, however I would like to see the text truncated with ellipsis instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: A single-line NSTextView? I don't get it. Aren't you looking for NSTextField?

Comment: Yes, since I can't seem to find a way to programmatically add a label to the view (searching seems to say it isn't possible...).

Comment: But how do I do it programmatically, as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: isn't possible? huh? what do you mean by "label?" anything you can do from IB you can do from code...

Comment: I was searching for NSLabel when the Label control was in fact a NSTextField. Hovering over worked.

Comment: cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you hover over the corresponding control in IB, you can see the declaration and brief documentation on the method that it triggers (usually the getter rather than the setter, but it's easy enough to infer one from the other).  So for example for the "Line Breaks" popup, you'll see the `lineBreakMode` method.  Then you can use your favorite method to find it in Xcode (e.g. "Open Quickly").

So what you want is:

```
[[someTextField cell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

or potentially:

```
[[someTextField cell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
[[someTextField cell] setTruncatesLastVisibleLine:YES];
```

Comment: The usage of cell is deprecated, so nowadays it should be `[someTextField setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];`

Answer (score 14):

It is correct what Nicholas wrote.

I like to add (because I spend some time searching for it) if you use Auto Layout for your `NSTextView` and surrounding `NSView` you should set your **Content Compression Resistance Priority** of the `NSTextView` less than [NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628-CH1-SW52) (e.g. 499).
Otherwise your NSTextView will not truncate its content.

Answer (score -3):

Another title for this could have been:

**How to STOP an NSTextField from resizing your window when its contents are longer than your window!**

Combining both Nicholas & Stephan's answers is what helped me.

I placed…

```
[[someTextField cell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

…in…

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
```

Or, for those that like to use interface builder…

Use Stephan's solution and change the NSTextField's Layout to Truncates.  Also, check to see what the Line Break is - Truncate Tail worked for what I needed.