# NSTextField does not show end ellipsis in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

I have a weird problem with a text field in my app that does not show end ellipses, even though it is set to do so. This is a view based NSTableView with these views:

[image]

"Local Name" is the field that gives me headaches. The constraints, hugging and compression resistence are set properly:

[image]

The money label has the standard values for hugging + compression resistance. Both name and value label have the same attributes set:

[image]

except for the alignment (name is left aligned, money value right aligned). What happens now is that the name label behaves as if I had set clipping. In order to see whether the name field changes its size I temporarily enabled a frame, which looks then so:

[image]

Which gives the impression as if the text field indeed resizes, but not the content. So what is missing here?

Note: when I change the compression resistance so that the money label shrinks, it shows the end ellipsis properly.

Comment: Are you making any programmatic modifications of the text field? Are you using a plain string value or an attributed string value?

Comment: Did you look at this [Truncate NSTextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171465/truncate-nstextview)? My _guess_ is that for some reason or another your layout is incorrect so that the NSTextView is generated in its entirety and then _clipped_ by the frame of the NSTableCellView.

Comment: There are no programmatic changes. The text comes from a bound objectValue property. I even removed the existing text field and added it freshly, only establishing the constrains and the binding.

Comment: The text field is not truncated by the cellview. This is what I tested with the temporary frame. And the money text is also part of that cell view and does not get clipped.

Comment: But what is the type of the property to which it is bound? What kind of object is supplied? Are there any value transformers involved?

Comment: The bound property is of type NSString. The objectValue is a core data object provided by a tree controller. I don't think this plays a role here as the money value is bound the same way and works as intented. A value transformer is not involved here.