# Truncate text in label

Tags: swift, autolayout, nstextfield, appkit

I am trying to use "Truncate Middle" on a single line label. I checked "Uses Single Line Mode", set Layout to "Truncates" and Line Break to "Truncate Middle" and I've set the Preferred width of the text field to "First Runtime Layout Width" and Content Hugging Priority to 250.

Here's my layout with the <Title> label on which I am trying to enable the truncation:
[image: layout]

In my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.stringValue = "This is a very very long title that should be truncated because it would enlarge the window unnecessary!"
}
```

It does not work, the window is enlarged to show the complete title and the user can't reduce its width.

Strangely, if I change the layout and line break from "Truncates"/"Truncate Middle" to "Wraps"/"Character Wrap", it works fine, but without the middle truncation.

[image: screenshot with wrap]

I am expecting truncate to work like this:

> This is a very very long text...rge the window unnecessary!

Maybe I'm missing something?

**EDIT:** Here's the sample project to test the issue: https://nofile.io/f/9s9OJXHaaw1/TestTruncate.zip

Comment: For truncate middle, your label should have a fixed width. check the trailing constraint for both labels(window & large text). currently it seems like trailing constraint is breaking and resulting in long label rather fixed distance from window label. you can check in UI debugging as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Auto Layout for your `NSTextView` and surrounding `NSView` you should set your **Content Compression Resistance Priority** of the `NSTextView` less than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (e.g. 499). Otherwise your `NSTextView` will not truncate its content. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13977990/7313752))

I was able to achieve this by setting `Content Compression Resistance Priority` of `Horizontal` from `500` to `499`.

You can do so by selecting your label -> Size Inspector -> Content Compression Resistance Priority

[image]

Giving me the following output:

[image]

Comment: `NSTextView` or `NSTextField`?

Answer (score 3):

This is something very simple. Just add this line in  `override func viewDidLoad()`

```
  yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
```

Or you can also set it from Interface Builder. Select your label and set `Line Break` as `Truncate Middle`.

[image]

Comment: This is what I am currently doing in AppKit (OS X), while it seems to work well in a Label with UIKit, on AppKit I can't resize the window less than the larger of the field with text. It must have something to do with the layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

For truncate middle, you have to set the alignment to centre as well.

Comment: I tried truncate tail and got the same issue. I tried truncate middle with center alignment and I still can't resize the window less than the preferred size. Maybe I am missing something, I am going to attach my sample project so you can see it by yourself.